# difference between returning a function and returning and executing a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, return-value

```
def a():
    print('Hello World')

def f():
    return a()

def g():
    a()

f()
g()
```

What is the difference between the function `f` and the function `g`?

What is the use of the keyword `return` in the funtion `f`?

Comment: Try this experiment again using a function `a` that returns something

Comment: In this example, nothing, because `a` returns `None`, as does any function without a `return` statement. It would be different if `a` returned, say, 5.

Comment: No code here returns a function. Returning a function would be `return a`, not `return a()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, functions always return something.  If there is no `return` statement, then the value `None` is returned.

---

In your code,

- `f()` **executes** `a()`, and **returns** the return value of `a()`, which happens to be `None`.
- `g()` **executes** `a()`, and ignores `a()`'s return value.

That said, when you have statements like `f()` and `g()`, you are ignoring the return values of these function calls.

---

As @Patrick suggested, let's try making `a()` return a value `42`. Then, instead of ignoring the values of function calls `f()` and `g()`, let's save their return values in variables `f_return_val` and `g_return_val`. Print them out and see what you get.

```
def a():
    print('Hello World')
    return 42

def f():
    return a()

def g():
    a()

f_return_val = f()
print(f_return_val)

g_return_val = g()
print(g_return_val)
```

---

You may find this article [What precisely does "return" in this code do?](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/51c0e35d7c82caace80008b1) helpful.

Comment: Important: `f()` also executes `a()`, and attempts to returns its return value. Compared to returning the function `a`.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yep you are right. I need a good way to phrase this.